# Can I use something similar to Angular's *ngFor in pyscript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pyscripter, pyscript

I am playing with Pyscript for the first time and I am trying to create a DOM element for each element in an array, similar to the *ngFor directive in Angular. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <py-script> 
dataSet = [1,2,3,4]

for i,x in enumerate(dataSet):
    pyscript.write("test", x)
    </py-script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to create a DOM element for each element in an array

To append a new DOM element, use the `append=True` parameter

```
pyscript.write("test", x, append=True)
```

The signature for pyscript.write

```
@staticmethod
def write(element_id, value, append=False, exec_id=0):
```

Source for `pyscript.write` [link](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/9334592c50dc2434ad896e2166abc52332a5ec8f/pyscriptjs/src/pyscript.py#L102)